# ReactNative fetch for Microsoft Azure Form Recognizer

Tags: azure, react-native, fetch, azure-form-recognizer

ReactNative version 0.66.3

Spent about 2 days trying all possible combinations on how to upload captured image from ReactNative camera into azure form recognizer, but I ran into different of errors. Can someone help with the right syntax?

Here I what I have tried so far and the errors received.

1. Using base64 string in form body - Error: The input data is not a valid image or password protected
2. blob data in form data in req body - Error: Same as above.
3. Add base64 in form data in req body - Error: [TypeError: Network request failed]

Here is my function that does the fetch.
Arguments:
uri - uri of the image in device.
base64data - base64 string

```
export async function executeScanService(uri, base64data) {
  try {
    const url = 'https://<my-endpoint>/formrecognizer/v2.1/prebuilt/receipt/analyze';

    // Using base64 string in request body doesnt work
    // const imgData = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64data; 

    // create a blob doesn't work either
   const result = await fetch(uri);
   const blobResult = result.blob();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image_data", blobResult, 'foo.jpeg');

    let options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': <my-key>,
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'      
      },
      body: formData    
};

    const response = await fetch(url, options);

    const respBody = await response.json();
    console.log('response Body', respBody, response.status);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error scan service', error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When specifying image data (Content-Type=image/jpeg), the body should contain the raw binary of the image, not a base64 encoding or a FormData.  In the code above, please try setting body to `atob(base64data)`.